# Android ViewPager IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I am using a ViewPager from the compatibility library. I get this exception quite often from the market reports.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1242)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1253)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:535)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:519)
```

Any ideas what might cause it?

Comment: See this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) for more information about why this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably calling `FragmentTransaction.commit()` in the wrong place. It needs to be called [before state is saved](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29).

Comment: yes that is true, but the hard thing is figuring out where :)

Comment: @Nicolay But if I only call commit() on Fragments onCreate() and activity is just created (onResume() still not called) can state has been saved?

Comment: this doesn't work if you are using DialogFragments. calling the show() method causes commit() to be called by the impl of DialogFragment, so you aren't able to substitute the "allowing state loss call" in that case.

Comment: Why would you want to use DialogFragments in a ViewPager?

Answer (score 8):

Try `commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `commit()`. Read the 
documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commitAllowingStateLoss).

Got answer from [here](https://groups.google.com/group/androiddevelopers/browse_thread/thread/74eacf9d7a32f8d3).

Comment: -1, this is *not* a good solution to this problem. All `commitAllowingStateLoss()` does is avoid the exception and allows the state loss to occur.

Comment: commitAllowingStateLoss it not a solution. Maybe it will work this time, but you can have problems to view a fragment sometimes.